# How to find the number of x per second given the time elapsed?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm benchmarking a websocket server and I am very poor at math so please forgive me.

I am [recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja00g.png) the amount of messages sent, and the elapsed time:

```
Players Connected: 2. Messages Sent: 3528, Elapsed Time: 180.7 seconds
```

I am wondering if it's possible to get the amount of messages (`i`)  that are being sent per second? I'm not really looking for code, but just on the algorithm needed. I have tried `Elapsed Time * i / 60` but with no luck.
Thanks ~

Comment: As a "reality check", think about some rounded numbers, say 3600 messages sent in 180 seconds.  Then 3600/180 = 20 "messages per second".  (Per means a ratio.)

Comment: I see @hardmath, that does make it easier to understand. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Number of messages)/(elapsed time) = (number of message per elapsed time unit)

This is the equation you want, because elapsed time is already in seconds no further corrections are needed.